# Does this Make Sense ? Riemannian Manifold Directional Derivative.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Take a Riemannian Manifold $(M,g)$, where the tangent space at $p\in M$ is denoted $T_p M$. Let $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$.

Does it make sense to ask for the directional derivative of $f$ at $p$ in direction $v\notin T_p M$?

I'm guessing no?

Answer (score 2):

This only makes sense if $f$ is a function on some manifold $N$, for which $M$ is a submanifold, but at that point, you don't even need to reference the space $M$ so it doesn't really make too much sense.

If $f$ were some function only on $M$ there is a non-unique extension of $f$ to some neighborhood of $M$ in $N$ for which you could certainly talk about a directional derivative in a direction non-tangent to $M$ but tangent to $N$, however, the non-uniqueness of this extension likely makes the result non-consistent based on your choice of extension.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't, just like it does not make sense to ask for the value of $f$ at $x\notin M$.

Both might make sense if you actually have some extension of $f$ to a bigger set (or manifold) in mind, but with the data you describe, it's nonsense.